# Adding new nodes to Kademlia, building Kademlia routing tables

Tags: p2p, dht, kademlia

I can't quite wrap my brain around the joining process of Kademlia DHTs. I've seen a few tutorials and presentations online, but they all seem to say things the same way and all psedo code etc is the same in most (actual copy/paste).

Can somebody give a high level walk through on this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm assuming you've read the [Kademlia paper](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~petar/papers/maymounkov-kademlia-lncs.pdf). Here's an excerpt from my article [An Introduction to Kademlia DHT & How It Works](http://gleamly.com/article/introduction-kademlia-dht-how-it-works)

**Some background information:**

1. When you have a Kademlia network running, there should always be a node that every other node knows about in order for them to join the network; lets call this the Bootstrap node `BN`.
2. `K` is a Kademlia constant that determines the size of the Buckets in a node's routing table as well as the amount of nodes a piece of Data should be stored on.

**Joining Process:**

3. A new Node `NN` is created with a NodeId (assigned by some method) and an IP Address (the IP of the computer it's hosted on).
4. `NN` sends a `LookupRequest(A.NodeId)` to `BN`. A Lookup Request basically asks the receiving node for the K-Closest nodes it knows to a given NodeId. In this case, `BN` will return the K-Closest nodes it knows to `NN`.
5. `BN` will now add `NN` to it's routing table, so `NN` is now in the network.
6. `NN` receives the list of K-Closest nodes to itself from `BN`. `NN` adds `BN` to it's routing table.
7. `NN` now pings these K nodes received from `BN`, and the ones that reply are added to it's Routing Table in the necessary buckets based on distance. By pinging these nodes, they also learn of `NN` existence and add `NN` to their Routing tables.
8. `NN` is now connected to the network and is known by nodes on the network.
9. `NN` now loops through each of it's K-Buckets

   ```
   foreach(K-Buckets as KB)         
       1. NN generates a random NodeId `RNID` // A NodeId that will be in KB 
       2. NN sends LookupRequest(RNID) to the K-Closest nodes it knows to RNID. 
       3. The response will be K nodes closest to RNID.
       4. NN now fills KB.
   ```

   `NN` does this for each of it's buckets to fill these buckets. 
   After this operation, `NN` has a better idea of the nodes on the network at different distances away from itself.

   **Note:** This step is not mandatory, however I did it in [My Implementation of Kademlia](https://github.com/JoshuaKissoon/Kademlia) so that each node will have better knowledge of the network when they join.

I wrote a full introduction to Kademlia at [An Introduction to Kademlia DHT & How It Works](http://gleamly.com/article/introduction-kademlia-dht-how-it-works)

Comment: Is it possible to perhaps simplify this a bit? Step 2 could be NN adds BN into its own routing table and performs a lookup operation on itself. Thus, the k-neighbors would become aware of the new node and add it into their own routing tables. I think this approach would save us from performing additional pings

Answer (score -3):

My guess is it uses some super nodes and geospatial informations to compute a minimum spanning tree. It can also compute a voronoi-diagram or the dual delaunay triangulation from the super nodes and use it to run a proximity search. Here is an example: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/math/spatial-searching.html.

Comment: I'll mark your answer right since your the only one who answered and the bounty runs out in in hour, but more info would be awesome. I like the idea of using triangular proximity searches, can you provide links with info on this?

Comment: Alas, that bounty was wasted. The answer is incorrect and the link 404s.

Comment: @the8472: Feel free to give a better answer!