# python p2p kademlia network simple example

Tags: python, networking, network-programming, p2p, kademlia

I have read [Kademlia paper](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~petar/papers/maymounkov-kademlia-lncs.pdf), some [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19329682/adding-new-nodes-to-kademlia-building-kademlia-routing-tables) on stackowrflow and other resources, but i still don't understand p2p...

I used [entangled](http://entangled.sourceforge.net/) [kademlia](https://github.com/bmuller/kademlia), learning examples, sources, but i still don't understand p2p...

Can anyone say me, how to create simple network with python using entangled or kademlia on my pc, where for example one `node` sends another 'hello' message when connected.

Comment: Check out the qadom project https://github.com/amirouche/qadom

Comment: above link 404s. Here is another (python3 asyncio) github project:
https://github.com/bmuller/kademlia